# Is there a keyboard shortcut to enter Reader View in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10

Is there a keyboard shortcut to entering Reader View in Firefox?

I visited Firefox support page at https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly but it doesn't mention one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, then <kbd>R</kbd> to open the Reader View quickly through the menu bar.

These shortcuts may be different in non-English versions of Firefox. Just figure out what the equivalent shortcuts are for (in the main menu) *View* → *Enter Reader View.*

---

As of Firefox 50, you can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on a Mac).

Comment: This depends entirely on the UI language. I doubt the key sequence you state would work, for example, on a French or Russian version of Firefox.

Comment: @xypha No View > Enter Reader View here, Firefox 44.0. See http://i.imgur.com/e3W8FPo.png

Comment: @DavidPostill - This works only when the page is compatible with Reader View, which superuser.com is not - try a different webpage such as http://gravitytales.com/blue-phoenix/bp-chapter-136/

Answer (score 6):

Yes there is, as of Firefox 50.0 (November 15, 2016). This shortcut was just added with the release of Firefox 50.

**Ctrl+Alt+R** (command+alt+r on Mac)

Source: [50.0 Release Notes](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/50.0/releasenotes/)

Answer (score 3):

#### Is there a keyboard shortcut to entering Reader View in Firefox?

**Short answer**:

No.

**Long answer**:

There is an [open (unassigned) bug report](http://[Bug%201144749%20-%20Create%20reader%20mode%20keyboard%20shortcut][1]) requesting that one be added:

> [image]

Source [Bug 1144749 - Create reader mode keyboard shortcut](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1144749)

Comment: Not as far as I know. I suggest you vote for the bug. If enough people do that it might be assigned and fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Now, you can press `F9` to toggle **Reader View**.

Comment: on which OS?  doesn't work for me on Linux